# Eclipse Tomcat Error: "Could not launch in profiling mode because no profilers are configured."

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm just starting with Java Web Application and I'm using this [tutorial series to learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSS0Tndfh6I&list=PLHqN89yRGMyAcwWcSWk59_S_-BQVn3Rrb&index=5).  I have followed all the instructions and installed all the instructed plug-ins and software successfully, and copied the given program (outputs a simple text line).  However, when I run it, it prompts the following

[image]

Could someone kindly guide me in what the problem is and what I might have done wrong?

P.s. I'm using Eclipse 'Neon' Java EE as my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to overview section of server.
2. Go to Server Options section.
3. Select (Publish module contexts to separate XML files).

[image]